# Optimization Problems

Tags: support, scope

There exists the case where you have code that **runs well**, only *slow*.
In these cases, is it on topic to post this as a problem that seeks for a solution?

Comment: [codereview.se] if you want to make working code run faster.

Comment: If you want to ask *why* something is slow and you have evidence that it should be faster, then by all means post on SO. I in particular like those kinds of questions.